# How to use sql to get the result with a certain condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with those 6 rows.

```
code | type_id | status | type
-----+--------+--------+-------
123  | 123456 | UPLOAD | PDF
123  | 456789 | UPLOAD | DOC
321  | 654321 | UPLOAD | PDF
321  | 897321 | DONE   | DOC
456  | 999888 | PEND   | PDF
456  | 777666 | UPLOAD | DOC
```

And I want to get the result as below with

case1 get type_id with UPLOAD UPLOAD under same code for PDF and doc

case2 get type_id with UPLOAD only with UPLOAD DONE under same code for PDF and doc

case3 dont show type_id when PEND and fail under same code for PDF and doc

```
code | type_id1 | type_id2
-----+----------+---------
123  | 123456   | 456789
321  | 654321   | null
null | null     | null   <for 456 dont show result
```

How can I process them with sql to show the result?

Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `LEFT JOIN`-ing your table with itself:

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.type_id AS type_id1, t2.type_id AS type_id2
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 
   ON t1.code = t2.code
   AND t2.type = 'DOC'
   AND t2.status = 'UPLOAD'
WHERE t1.type = 'PDF' AND t1.status = 'UPLOAD'
```

This will take all rows with `PDF` and `UPLOAD`, and "add" the `type_id2` value only if there is a row with matching `code`, `type = DOC` and `status = UPLOAD`

For the data you gave, the expected result should be

```
code | type_id1 | type_id2
-----+----------+---------
123  | 123456   | 456789
321  | 654321   | null
```

You can [try it here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mXykRKKYYMhfMpsGZckwXZ/0)

=== Version 2 ===============================================================

Here is an updated version based on my interpretation of your comments:

```
SELECT t1.code, 
    CASE 
      WHEN t1.status = 'UPLOAD' AND t2.status != 'PEND' 
      THEN t1.type_id 
      ELSE null 
    END AS type_id1,
    CASE 
      WHEN t2.status = 'UPLOAD' AND t1.status != 'PEND' 
      THEN t2.type_id 
      ELSE null 
    END AS type_id2
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 
   ON t1.code = t2.code
   AND t2.type = 'DOC'
WHERE t1.type = 'PDF'
```

You can try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mXykRKKYYMhfMpsGZckwXZ/2)

In case you don't want rows with `code | null | null`, you can remove both `AND t#.status != 'PEND'` from the `WHEN` clauses, and add at the very end of the query: `AND t1.status != 'PEND' AND t2.status != 'PEND'`, like the 2nd query in the fiddle.

Comment: thank you for your reply! it works! but how about if 456  | 999888 | PEND   | PDF
456  | 777666 | UPLOAD | DOC

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works! But for the status with doc type can be swap~ PDF with DONE, DOC with PEND. If with this case, the sql cannot show the correct result~ could you mind to teach me how to do that?

Comment: Can you add those examples and their desired outcome in your question? for example, if PDF is DONE and DOC is UPLOAD, should the "doc" type_id be written in type_id1 or type_id2? and for 456, do you still want a row to show `456 | null | null`?

Comment: @fizz try to add expected result set by editing your question( tabular form) so that the community can help instead of asking many doubts.